# Entity Framework 4 / Linq: How to OrderBy() a hierarchical Entity?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I have a ViewModel carved from several Entity relations:

```
Products[].Prices[].Others[].myField
```

How do I order Products[] by the nested myField?  When I do the Where clause, it's like this:

```
Products.Where( p => p.Prices.Any( q => q.Others.Any( r => r.myField == 4)));
```

So if I wanted to Products.OrderBy() and order by myField, what would the Expression look like?

```
Products.OrderBy( p => p.Prices.SelectMany( ??
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify with an example result that you are trying to pull back? Nesting that deep is usually used for including relationships in the final result, not actually affecting the query itself.

Comment: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx it's helped me out a couple times.

Answer (score 1):

As you have several prices below your product you need to select which one to sort on, like

```
Products.OrderBy( p => p.Prices.First().Others.First().myField )
```

or if you want to order by the highest price

```
Products.OrderBy( p => p.Prices.OrderByDescending(price => price.Value).First().Others.First().myField )
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume prices has a field `Value` which is primary type or Comparable type so you have:

```
Products.OrderBy( p => p.Prices.Average(x=>x.Value))
```

or

```
Products.OrderBy( p => p.Prices.Min(x=>x.Value))
```